# how to logout from wso2 jaggeryapps that i created parallel to store

Tags: wso2

I have requirement to have hyperlink in my jaggeryapps that if users click on that then he should be logged out of application.
This logout functionality should be as same as we have wso2 store user logged in page .

Before this i have created login functionality inside jaggeryapps and there if user clicks on login link this will be redirected to href="/store/site/pages/login.jag" and user is able to login here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you used the href="/store/site/pages/login.jag" to login the user there is a jaggery endpoint to logout. Just call this endpoint end the user will be logged out.

http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag?action=logout

More information about the endpoint is provided in the official documentation.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Store+APIs#StoreAPIs-Logout